# Remove numeric tags in dynamic json using java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Content in a String and sometimes it has numeric tags which has to be removed.

Below is a sample JSON content

```
{
"Test": {
   "P1": false,
    P2": {
        "2000": [
        {
        "DP": "DP TEST",
        "id": "ID TEST"
        }
                ],
        "4000": [
        {
        "DP": "DP TEST",
        "id": "ID TEST"
        }
        ],
        "5000": [
        {
        "DP": "DP TEST",
        "id": "ID TEST"
        }
        ],
        "8000": [
        {
        "DP": "DP TEST",
        "id": "ID TEST"
        }
        ],
        "6000": [
        {
        "DP": "DP TEST",
        "id": "ID TEST"
        }
        ]
    },
    "P3": "XYZ",
    "P4": ABC,
    "VL": "",
    "PL": [{
            "start_date": 1496480880.0,
            "id": "TEST1"
        }
    ],
},
"PS": "AMD",
"links": [{
        "LOC": "en-US",
        "PS": "AMD"
    }, {
        "LOC": "fr-CA",
        "PS": "AMD"
    }
]   
}
```

In the above case "P2" tag has numeric keys and in such case we need to display it as  after converting the string to JSON. Which means, we need to remove the tags which has numeric keys.

I have tried with org.json, org.json.simple and com.gson as well but nothing seems to work.

I am able to read each line using the below code snipet

```
public static void printJson(JsonElement jsonElement) {

    // Check whether jsonElement is JsonObject or not
    if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens = ((JsonObject) jsonElement).entrySet();
        if (ens != null) {
            // Iterate JSON Elements with Key values
            for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en : ens) {
                try{
                    Integer.parseInt(en.getKey());
                    break;
                }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    if("".equals(str)){
                        str = "\"" + en.getKey() + "\": {";
                    }else{
                        str = str + "\"" + en.getKey() + "\": {";
                    }
                    System.out.println(en.getKey() + "-----" + en.getValue());
                }
                printJson(en.getValue());
            }
        }
    } 

    // Check whether jsonElement is Arrary or not
    else if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray jarr = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
                // Iterate JSON Array to JSON Elements
                for (JsonElement je : jarr) {
                    printJson(je);
                }
    }

    // Check whether jsonElement is NULL or not
    else if (jsonElement.isJsonNull()) {
        // print null
        System.out.println("null");
    } 
    // Check whether jsonElement is Primitive or not
    else if (jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        // print value as String
        if("".equals(str)){
            str = "\"" + jsonElement.getAsString() + "\"";
        }else{
            str = str + "\"" + jsonElement.getAsString() + "\"";
        }
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());
    } 
    }
```

But am unable to remove the numeric keyed tags. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: If you *"remove the tags which has numeric keys"*, then `P2` will be empty. Please show what your expect output to be. --- Also, what is `str`?

Comment: Yeah I need to show a empty tag for p2. just this <P2/> and str is a global string variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to strip `JSONObject` keys that are numeric, you can do it like this:

```java
private static void strip(JSONObject obj) {
    for (Iterator<String> keyIter = obj.keys(); keyIter.hasNext(); ) {
        String key = keyIter.next();
        if (key.matches("\\d+"))
            keyIter.remove();
        else
            strip(obj.get(key));
    }
}
private static void strip(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
        strip((JSONObject) value);
    } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
        for (Object elem : (JSONArray) value)
            strip(elem);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path/to/file.json")), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(input);
strip(obj);
System.out.println(obj.toString(2));
```

*Output*

```
{
  "PS": "AMD",
  "Test": {
    "P1": false,
    "P2": {},
    "P3": "XYZ",
    "P4": "ABC",
    "VL": "",
    "PL": [{
      "id": "TEST1",
      "start_date": 1.49648088E9
    }]
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "LOC": "en-US",
      "PS": "AMD"
    },
    {
      "LOC": "fr-CA",
      "PS": "AMD"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks much! I am now able to read the child elements, check for numeric and remove them. Your answer is really helpful and very precise. But there is one issue still. It is checking till 2 - 3 levels of elements. But if I have the set of numeric key elements at 4th or next level, it doesnt check those element keys. It simply shows them as is. doesnt remove them. Is there any possibility to remove them in all levels?

Comment: @Lettisha Code checks to infinitely deep levels.

Comment: Hey Andreas, just one last question - Is there any possibility to rename the integer keys to some string keys? I know we cannot read the data from the tags which have integer keys. But am just curios if we can read the data of integer keys as well and rename such keys to some valid key

Comment: @Lettisha I don't think you can *rename* the key, but you can remove it and add it with a different name.

Comment: Hey I got the solution. I just copied my json string to another string and using your solution I am checking if there are numeric keys. Whenever I get a numeric key am replacing that numeric in my new json string by adding ! as prefix. Thanks much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with Andreas help.

But I had another issue while working on it. It was working fine for 2-3 levels only. After 3rd level, if there are any numeric keys, they were not being removed.

I have added one more condition to check if the object is an instance of org.json.JSONObject and then check if that JSONObject has any JSONArray.

Sample code given below

```
if (value instanceof org.json.JSONArray) {
        for (int i=0; i< ((org.json.JSONArray) value).length(); i++) {
            try{
                if(((org.json.JSONArray) value).get(i).getClass().getName() =="org.json.JSONObject"){
                    strip((JSONObject) ((org.json.JSONArray) value).get(i));
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
            }
        }
    }
```